# How can I install protobuf in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, protocol

I want to make one project on java using netty and protobuf for the communication between client and server. Please guide me how could I install protobuf on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 12):

Taken from http://www.confusedcoders.com/random/how-to-install-protocol-buffer-2-5-0-on-ubuntu-13-04:

> Protocol buffer is a serialization format developed by Google. It is
>   Interface driven and is useful for applications that communicate over
>   the wire. Below are the steps for protocol buffer installation.
>
> 1. Download protocol buffer. Protocol buffer libs can be downloaded here. [Download protocol buffer](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases).
> 2. Check if g++ compiler is installed on box. Protocol buffer needs g++ compiler to be present on your box before it can be built. This is
>      a crisp post on how to install g++ compiler on your box. [Install g++
>      compiler](http://www.confusedcoders.com/misc/how-to-install-g-compiler-for-cc-on-ubuntu-13-04).
> 3. Extract the protocol buffer archive and switch to the extracted directory.
> 4. Inside the extracted directory hit the below commands to install protocol buffer. These may take a while, kindly be patient.
>
>    ```
>    ./configure
>    make
>    make check
>    sudo make install
>    protoc --version
>    ```
> 5. That's it. Protocol buffer version 2.5.0 is installed on your box.
> 6. Note: Sometimes the latest version of protocol version does not load up. So we can do it manually by this command
>
>    ```
>    sudo ldconfig
>    protoc --version
>    ```

Answer (score 6):

It appears that 12.04 is [one of the first versions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/protobuf) containing protobuf under apt-get!

Simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-java protobuf-compiler
```

and you should be all set to use protobufs with Java.

That being said, 12.04 only supports getting up to protobuf v2.4 this way. So if you need newer features, you'll need to obtain it from the github as described in the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

As to me, I install protpbuf 2.6.1 in ubuntu12

#### 1. download

https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz

#### 2. install

```
tar -zxvf protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz  #unzip

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential 

cd protobuf-2.6.1/ 

./configure

make -j10

make check -j10 

sudo make install -j10
```

#### 3. check install successfully

protoc --version  # if echo 'libprotoc 2.6.1' then successfully

#### 4. If failed

If it shows error "protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
"

sudo updatedb
locate libprotoc.so.9

/usr/local/lib/libprotoc.so.9
/usr/local/lib/libprotoc.so.9.0.1

So we need add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

vi ~/.bashrc
then add

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Then:

source ~/.bashrc

protoc --version

you will get `libprotoc 2.6.1`

Comment: instead of  `sudo updatedb locate libprotoc.so.9` , you can execute 'sudo ldconfig'

Answer (score 1):

## 2019 update

Here's how I installed protobuf in order to [build](https://github.com/MisterTea/EternalTerminal/pull/203/files) Eternal Terminal (a pretty amazing terminal emulator that combines `autossh` with `mosh` but gives you [native scrolling](https://eternalterminal.dev/)):

```
sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```